# Required Checkout Field Based on Shipping Method - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'd like to make `billing_last_name` not required if local pickup is chosen.

Trying something like this:

```
function xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields($fields) {
    $shipping_method ='local_pickup'; // Set the desired shipping method to hide the checkout field(s).
    global $woocommerce;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method) {
       $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'][ 'required' ] = false;
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

But it's not working.

Is there a proper solution?

Comment: This should work normally. Please show us the hook too. Where do you hook into?

Comment: Oh, I think this is the problem, I didn't write a hook. How I should do it?

Comment: I've provided you an answer, see first line (add_filter).

Comment: Thanks! Almost perfect, except, I need to update page with selected shipping method to disable mandatory option. Is it possible to make this field without refreshing page? Like with Ajax or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your updated code with a hook:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields');

function xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields($fields) {
    $shipping_method ='local_pickup'; // Set the desired shipping method to hide the checkout field(s).
    global $woocommerce;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method) {
       $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'][ 'required' ] = false;
    }
    return $fields;
}
```